# FutureBuilder not populating value

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-http

In my `main.dart` I have an async function to get data from an URL.

```
getShopLength() async {
  final queryParameters = {
    'api_key': '123',
    'user_id': '123',
    'lat': '123',
    'long': '123',
    'km': '123',
  };
  var response = await http.get(Uri.https('google.de','getSth', queryParameters));
  var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  List<Shops> shops = [];

  for(var x in jsonData) {
  Shops shop = Shops(x['name'], x['slogan']);
  shops.add(shop);
  }
  return shops.length;
}
```

In my `home.dart` I want to get the value from `getShopLength()` but I always get the error: `type 'Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>?'`

I try to save the return value into `valueShop` and pass it to                 `buildRestaurantRow('Top Angebote', context, valueShop)`

home.dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var valueShop = "0";

    FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getShopLength(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            valueShop = snapshot.data;
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
    );


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildSearchBar(context),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            buildRestaurantRow('Top Angebote', context, valueShop),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            buildRestaurantList(context),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            buildCategoryRow('Nach Kategorie', context),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            buildCategoryList(context),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            buildCategoryRow('Deine Favoriten', context),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            buildFriendsList(),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem lies here:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getShopLength(),
```

Your future builder has a type of string, which means that the future should be of type `Future<String>`, but when you declared the function `getShopLength`, you did this:

```
getShopLength() async {
```

You did not give it a return type, because of that, the default return type is `Future<dynamic>`.

The obvious solution is giving the function a return type, but you have another problem:

The futurebuilder expects a string value, but the function returns a number, so which is it?

If you want to return a string of the length, you can just do this:

```
Future<String> getShopLength() async  {
  ...
  return shops.length.toString();
}
```

Or you can also change the futurebuilder's value to be int:

```
Future<int> getShopLength() async  {
  ...
  return shops.length;
}
...
int valueShop = 0;

FutureBuilder<int>(
  future: getShopLength(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      valueShop = snapshot.data;
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

### Side note:

Ok, I have a couple of things to mention about your code:
First of all, on your `getShopsLength` function, you have two lists, `jsonData` and `shops`, you don't actually need both, you can just use one:

```
var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
return jsonData.length // no need for the shops list.
```

Second of all, what's up with your builder code?? You first declare a `FutureBuilder`, but then completely ignore it and move on to a `Scaffold` widget? I believe the scaffold code should be inside the future builder, as it stands, you will never see the circular progress indicator:

From:

```
var valueShop = '0';

FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getShopLength(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            valueShop = snapshot.data;
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
    );

return Scaffold(...);
```

To:

```
return FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: getShopLength(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      var valueShop = snapshot.data;
      return Scaffold(...);
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
);
```